# Obtaining sample variance from grouped data for goodness of fit test

Tags: self-study, variance, standard-deviation, goodness-of-fit

This is a practice question I came across when dong some goodness of fit test examples.A company sells cloths by mail order.The size of clothes is defined by hip size; thus the height of customers of a particular customer may vary considerably.
Data set of heights sent in by customers of size 18 is given.Data set includes class interval,class mid mark and frequency.

a) Given that $\sum$f=265,  $\sum fx$=40735,   $\sum fx^2$=6299425 estimate mean and standard deviation of heights.
b)The company decides that it is not possible to produce a range of garments for a particular size suitable for customers of different heights.A single height must be chosen and it is proposed that mean height should be chosen for this.Comment on this suggestion as it applies to customers of size 18 and make an alternative proposal.

My question is how can I calculate **sample** variance from $\sum$f=265,  $\sum fx$=40735,   $\sum fx^2$=6299425
 From V(X)=E(X$^2$)- E[X]$^2$ what I get is population variance and not sample variance right? For sample variance I should divide by n-1.So how can I get **sample** variance value?  Also why does it ask to **estimate** values for standard deviation?This question hasn't specified that a sample is being taken.So won't these be population variance and mean I am calculating?

Please help me to answer part b?

Comment: **Hints:** Is the company trying to make decisions about the size-18 customers who have sent in their heights or about all future customers who order size 18?  What is the sample?  What quantitative information do you have about the sample?  What is the population?  Do you know its mean height?  If so, compute it; if not, consider how you could estimate the mean from a sample.  Similarly, do you know the SD of heights in the population?  If not, how would you estimate it?

Comment: I think the  company would want to make decisions about future customers so this would be a sample, therefore sample mean and sample variance should be used as estimates for population mean and variance.But then with the given values I don't know how to compute sample variance

Comment: I was able to do part 'a' with the hint you provided.Please help me to understand part **b**?I don't know what else can be used other than the mean height

Comment: Part (b) asks you to interpret the answer you obtained in part (a). How large is the estimated sample variance?  What does that tell you about how well the mean describes the height of a typical customer?

Comment: mean was 153.72 and Standard deviation was 11.9375.Since there's a lot of variability in the data set it is not reasonable to take mean as the height. There are data points lying even 3*standard deviations away from the mean in(180-category).But what else should be used as the estimator